# Write style from code behind c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, coding-style, resources

i've write this code in resorces.xaml in order to apply it at all button in my project:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Style="{DynamicResource rectangle_style}" Cursor="Hand">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Attempts\image.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content=""/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

i would edit this style from code behind in C# because i'll want to can change imagesource dynamically from code, how i can write it from code behind C#?

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in code. If you need dynamic ImageSources, put a `public string ImageSource {get;set;}` somewhere in your ViewModel and Bind the image to that.

Comment: You *really* don't want to do this, unless you are absolutely forced to; dealing with the creation (and all the associated structure) of WPF ui elements is an onerous and fragile undertaking.

Comment: @JerKimball you cheated... you moved 2 pieces in the ChessBoard while I was sleeping. I will continue that when I get some time

Comment: @HighCore Hah - that's what happens when I can't sleep: I drink scotch and code random crap. :)

Comment: sorry but i would only to change one image! O.O

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have time to translate this line by line, I have written a complete article in how to create DataTemplates/Styles in code behind.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29699/WPF-How-to-create-Styles-in-code-and-magical-Conte

That should get you started

Although like others have stated I think you should be going for a ViewModel type of approach and letting the binding do it.

Another approach though is to hijack a pretty unused property (or better still add an attached property) such as Tag, and use that for your Image name. And then you can create a ControlTemplate that can be part of your Style which will look in the specific Button (the one you are applying the Style to) for the Tag which will be a path to an image.

So something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="bordereredButtonTemplateWithMouseAndPropHiJacking" 
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
            BorderThickness="2" Width="auto" 
            Visibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                 Path=Tag}" Width="20" 
                 Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            <ContentPresenter  
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                Width="auto" Height="auto"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="border" 
                Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="border" 
                Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then when you want to use this in your XAML you would do

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource bordereredButtonTemplateWithMouseAndPropHiJacking}"   
Tag="c:\temp\image1.jpg"/>
<Button Template="{StaticResource bordereredButtonTemplateWithMouseAndPropHiJacking}" 
Tag="c:\temp\image1.jpg"/>
```

For you, you will want to make the Template part of the Style but you get the idea I hope

Comment: Sacha, you're one of my idols, but I have to disagree with you on this. Even if the OP has no other chance but to do this in code, the preferred method is to still use XAML and a XAMLReader, something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way)

Comment: I actually agree with you I think XAML approach is the way to go. However since he asked about doing Style in code I just pointed a resource out to him. I think he should either go MVVM and have a mini vm which holds list for button objects. Or use you method, which is also cool